# Couchbase async batch error handling

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, couchbase, observable

I guess, I've got a brain explosion from Observables+Couchbase async api :)
Could anybody help me, please?
Have been fighting with batch operations for a few days already and still can't understand how to do batch operations with proper error handling.

Let's say, I want to update some documents in Couchbase in bulk.
If I used sync API, it would look like:

```
List< JsonDocument> items = getItems(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
// getItems - some method which calls bucket.get() for specified keys

for (JsonDocument item : items) {
   try {
      try {
         item.content().put("age", 42);
         bucket.replace(item);
      } catch (CASMismatchException e) {
        // retry
        bucket.get(item.id()).content().put("age", 42);
        bucket.replace(item);
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // handle error which doesn't stop execution for other items
      // for example, add item id to list of failed items in response
      errorHandler.handleError(item.id(), e);
   }
}
```

But this is not parallel, and documentations says async API is more efficient.
What I can't understand is how to create such flow via Observables, I tried:

```
Observable.from(items)
.flatMap(item -> {
   item.content().put("age", 42);
   return bucket.async().replace(item);
})
.onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
   // what to do? return another observable which does retry logic above?
   // how do I know what item has failed?
   // I don't have ID of that item, nor I can extract it from passed Exception
   // why onErrorResumeNext is getting called only once (if one item fails)
   // and is not called for other items?
})
.subscribe(); // also need Subscriber with onError (otherwise there are warnings in log)
```

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: I guess you better need build Observable via Observable.create with a try catch then retry directly in that, if retry work emit this item, if not then emit the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
  Observable.from(items)
            .flatMap(item -> {
                item.content().put("age", 42);
                return bucket.async()
                        .replace(item)
                        .retry((count, throwable) -> count == 1 && throwable instanceof CASMismatchException)
                        .onErrorReturn(e -> {
                            errorHandler.handleError(item.id(), e);
                            return null; //or item, if you need the item further down the stream
                        })
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()); //not sure if it's needed with bucket.async()
            })
            .subscribeOn(<something>) //with this scheduler the put() method will be executed 
            .subscribe();
```

the idea is to separate each item handling to a separate Observable via `flatMap()`, as each retry logic is for single item, not for the entire stream.
the retry operator operates with predicate that gives you retry count and the exception, so in your case we retry for the first time only with the specific `CASMismatchException` exception, then for error we can simply do `onErrorReturn` and handle other errors, you can even return the item if you want to continue to process it.
One thing to note is the schedulers, I'm not sure if Couchbase operate by default on `io()` when doing `async()` call.  also, consider that this line:

```
 item.content().put("age", 42);
```

will be executed on the last subscribeOn() as it will be done on the main stream subscription scheduler.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try to follow your advice. The case I've described is very simplified, however the idea about catching error via item Observable rather than list Observable is what I really missed and now it will most likely solve my problem.